# Number of graphs plotted using matplotlib in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, data-visualization

I was confused with the usage of `plt.plot()` multiple times. According to my thinking, each call of 'plt.plot()' should plot a different graph. But in the below code it only creates 2 plots. Is it because the functions are plotted in the same graph if they have the same x-values? If so, how would someone create a separate graph with same x-values?
Thanks

```
plt.plot(x_vals, y_vals,'o',label='Data Points')
plt.plot(x_vals, best_fit, 'r-', label='SVM Regression Line',linewidth=3)
plt.plot(x_vals, best_fit_upper, 'r--', linewidth=2)
plt.plot(x_vals, best_fit_lower, 'r--', linewidth=2)
plt.ylim([0,10])
plt.legend(loc='lower right')
plt.title('Sepal Length vs Pedal Width')
plt.xlabel('Pedal Width')
plt.ylabel('Sepal Length')
plt.show()
plt.plot(train_loss,'k--',label='Train Set Loss')
plt.plot(test_loss,'r--',label='Test Set Loss')
plt.title('L2 Loss per Generation')
plt.xlabel('Generation')
plt.ylabel('L2 Loss')
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To separate the plots to different figures, you need to use `plt.figure()` before each one.
For example-

```
plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(x_vals, y_vals,'o',label='Data Points')
plt.figure(2)
plt.plot(x_vals, best_fit, 'r-', label='SVM Regression Line',linewidth=3)
plt.show() #will show all graphs
```

Comment: I see, but the code in the question does not use plt.figure yet plots 2 different graphs?

Comment: Not exactly- `plt.figure(1)` creates a figure that you can edit, `plt.show()` simply shows the existing figures. In this case they behaves the same